# Как на Python обратиться к определенной строке?

Tags: python

Например  я хочу разместить def в конце кода, а вызвать его примерно в середине кода, как мне это сделать? Например:

```
1 print(".")
2 print("..")
3 iii() # тут должно быть обращение к 7 и 8 строке
4 print("....")
5
6
7 def iii():
8     print("...")
```

Comment: Никак. Выполнение будет построчно

Comment: @gil9red печально(

Comment: а зачем вам это?

Comment: Возникла необходимость добавить def в конце кода, для его сокращения

Comment: @OMEGA, будь это компилируемым языком, то в том месте это было возможно, но понадобилось бы объявить функции, а, например, в конце кода определить ее тело :)

Comment: Вспомнил `GO TO` на `Basic`, всплакнул ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из способов сделать это:

```py
def main():
    print(".")
    print("..")
    iii()
    print("....")


def iii():
    print("...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Результат:

```
.
..
...
....
```

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы хотите сделать, делается вот так

```
def iii():
    print("...")
print(".")
print("..")
iii() 
print("....")
```

Результат работы:

```
.
..
...
....
```

Попробуйте перед тем, как начинать использовать некоторую конструкцию, прочитать в книжечке ее формат и особенности использования.

Comment: Я знаю, я просто хотел узнать, можно ли как нибудь обращаться к определенным строкам в коде

Comment: А ничего, что вызов функции -  это несколько не то, что "обращаться к определенным строкам в коде"? И если что-  оператора GOTO в Python нет. Слава Богу.